# PHP ajax Multiple data transfer

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

In the code below it works when I pass data. But it doesn't work when I pass multiple data. I have used data from the table row. I can't catch my mistake.

**ajax_update_bill_status.php**

```
 if($_POST['unique_id']!=""):
        extract($_POST);
     
        $last_bill=$_POST['last_bill'];
        $last_bill_date = date('Y-m-d');
    
          $sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE tbl_clients SET last_bill=?, last_bill_date=? WHERE unique_id=?");
          $sql->bind_param("ssi", $last_bill, $last_bill_date, $unique_id);
     $sql->execute()
     
    endif;
```

**index.php**

```
 <a class="transfer btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-appd="ok" data-appds="2022-04-12" href=""  >Transfer</a>

<script>
   $(document).on('click','.transfer',function(){
   var element = $(this);
   var unique_id = element.attr("data-appd");
   var last_bill = element.attr("data-appds");
   var info = 'unique_id=' + unique_id;
   var last = 'last_bill=' + last_bill;
   if(confirm("Are you sure you want to transfer this?"))
   {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax_update_bill_status.php",
      data: info,last,
      success: function(){
    }
   });
     $(this).parents("tr").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
     .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
    }
   return false;
   });
</script>
```

Comment: `extract($_POST);` is a security no-no.  Do not let users have the authority to declare unsanitized globally scoped variables in your applications.

Comment: You don't need to pass `date('Y-m-d')` into your sql from php.  Just use `CURRENT_DATE` https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-current_date-function.php -- this way you pass fewer parameters to your prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

`data: info, last` is not how you combine `info` and `last` in the `data:` option. They should be a single string, with the parameters separated by `&`.

However, it's better to use an object instead of a string; `$.ajax()` will automatically convert this to a properly encoded string.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.transfer', function() {
  var element = $(this);
  var unique_id = element.data("appd");
  var last_bill = element.data("appds");
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to transfer this?")) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax_update_bill_status.php",
      data: {unique_id, last_bill},
      success: function() {}
    });
    $(this).parents("tr").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#003"
      }, "slow")
      .animate({
        opacity: "hide"
      }, "slow");
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: This advice has been given on Stack Overflow a hundred times in the last decade.  Please close basic duplicates -- you know very well what they look like.

Comment: @mickmackusa I've never seen the OP's mistaken syntax before.

Comment: [sigh] the dupe box at the top of this page says: "This question already has answers here:"

Comment: Should the OP access these pieces of data with `$_POST[0]` and `$_POST[1]`?

Comment: @mickmackusa No, it's an object, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong use

```
data: info,last,
```

```html
<a class="transfer btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-appd="ok" data-appds="2022-04-12" href=""  >Transfer</a>

<script>
   $(document).on('click','.transfer',function(){
   var element = $(this);
   var unique_id = element.attr("data-appd");
   var last_bill = element.attr("data-appds");
   var info = 'unique_id=' + unique_id;
   var last = 'last_bill=' + last_bill;
   if(confirm("Are you sure you want to transfer this?"))
   {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax_update_bill_status.php",
      data: ""+info+"&+"+last+"",
      success: function(){
    }
   });
     $(this).parents("tr").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
     .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
    }
   return false;
   });
</script>
```

Comment: You are making lots of contributions, but not great ones.  Questions that you are choosing to answer can be and should be closed as duplicates instead of answering. Please only answer clear, complete, unique, and on-topic questions. Every answer should include an educational explanation with the intent to educate and empower not only the asker but thousands of future researchers.  Please stop posting "for speed" and start posting "for quality" so that your answer make Stack Overflow better, not worse.